# How can I 'fill in' the sea in a DTM raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem

I am using OS Terrain 50 data, mosaicked with R, to make some nice 3D maps using Rayshader. However, for coastal and island areas, there are large gaps where the sea is. How can I easily fill these in in QGIS to prevent gaps in my rayshader model? Screenshot below of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Being the sea, do you wish to fill the gap by a constant value such as zero? Or interpolate them by nearby cell values?

Comment: @kazuhito Just zero would be fine, to avoid a gap in the 3D model.

Answer (score 1):

There would be several approaches; one tool I would recommend is SAGA **Reclassify values (single)** in the `Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Raster tools`.

Assuming your NoData value is `-99999`,

(1) Activate **Reclassify values (single)** tool.

(2) Set parameters and run the tool:

- old value = `-99999`
- new value = `0.0000`
- operator - `[0] =`

[image]

The tool will return a new layer `Reclassified Grid` of which `-99999` is replaced by `0`. Please check the cell value by Identify Features tool.

[image]